# Dynamically sorting a DbDataReader using LINQ

Tags: linq, ado.net

I am very new to LINQ and have a class method, which when called, returns a DbDataReader object. How would I sort this dynamically using a LINQ query expression where the sort expression is provided as a string (e.g. "LastName DESC")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't take any credit - links in this question to Dynamic Linq and how to do it without:

[Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)